# Why I am getting an oci runtime error when running a simple docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I want to create a simple image that when i run it i can see its output on the terminal. I tried two ways:

first way:

- I created a simple bash file hello.sh containing `echo "hello"`
- Then I created a dockerfile containing:

`FROM Scratch
 ADD script.sh /usr/local/bin/run.sh
 CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run.sh"]`

- I created the image using: `go build -t hello_image .`
- And then ran the image using: `go run hello_image`
- I received and error: `standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

Then I tried a second way:

- I created  a Dockerfile containing:

`FROM Scratch
 CMD echo "This is a test."`

- I built the image
- I ran the image
- I got an error:

`Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory.`

Can anyone help me in solving this errors or even explain what should I do to create a simple image of my code and see its output when I run it. Thank you

Comment: What do you refer to by 'Scratch'? Did you create an image by that name, which has no files in it at all?

Comment: `scratch` is a "special" image name that represents an "empty" base image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scratch` image is literally "empty". There are no files provided by the base image, most importantly there is no shell (`bash`, `sh`, etc).

When you tried to run the bash script it failed because there is no `bash` binary to run it.
When you tried to run `echo` it failed because the `echo` binary does not exist in the image.

If you want to run a program from `script` you need to compile it as a static ELF binary. This is easy to do some some languages (go lang for example).

If you'd like to just run a bash script, you should try creating an image from `alpine` which is a minimal linux distribution:

```
FROM alpine:3.4
CMD echo "hello"
```

Or

```
FROM alpine:3.4
RUN  apk add -U bash
COPY script.sh /usr/local/bin/run.sh
CMD  ["bash", "/usr/local/bin/run.sh"]
```

Comment: between Scratch and a good light disitribution like Alpine, you have busybox https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/ see for example http://yasermartinez.com/blog/posts/creating-super-small-docker-images.html